# How can I implement the Multer to upload the images in the server after the joi validation in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary, joi

I want to upload the images to the Cloudinary server using Multer. My implementation is not working the way I want. I made the middleware for multer and cloudinary as:

**middleware**

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const cloudinaryStorage = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");

cloudinary.config({
//My Cloudinary Data
});

exports.cloudinaryStorage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  folder: "game_zone",
  allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gid", "pdf"],
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); // The file on cloudinary would have the same name as the original file name
  }
});
```

and in my route i.e **game.js** i passed the middleware also in

```
const multer = require("multer");
const { Category } = require("../models/category");
const { Game, validate } = require("../models/games");
const { cloudinaryStorage } = require("../middleware/cloudStorage");

const upload = multer({ storage: cloudinaryStorage });


router.post("/", upload.array("gameImage", 5), async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);
  let categories = [];
  categories = req.body.category_id;

  let category = await Category.findById({ _id: req.body.category_id });

  if (!category) return res.status(400).send(`category invalid`);

  let game = new Game({
    name: req.body.name,
    category: {
      _id: category._id,
      name: category.name
    },
    img: req.file.url
  });
  const result = await game.save();
  res.send(result);
 });
```

The upload works but it should upload the images when there is no error being thrown by joi.

Comment: I have this issue @RaviSingh . Did you find a solution?

Comment: not actually still finding

Comment: You should check this link out. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/150
I think i can work around the what was suggested. Will share once i come up with the solution later on @RaviSingh